# Use another Google account in Chrome only

Tags: google-account, chrome-for-android

My Android phone has 2 Google accounts set up. I see those when I go to `Google > Account` in my phone settings:

- `Google Account 1` (main user)
- `Google Account 2`

Google Chrome is configured to use `Google Account 1`, and syncs history, bookmarks, etc.

**Question**: How can I configure Chrome to make it so that it's the history/bookmarks from `Google Account 2` that are synchronized, while keeping `Google Account 1` as the main user at the OS level?

**What I've tried**: From Chrome, go to Settings, then click my account: it brings me to a view where I can choose between `Google Account 1` or `Google Account 2` (or add another account). Clicking either account 1 or 2 takes me to a lists of the various accounts from various apps I have on the system (!?) (Airbnb, Facebook, Meetup, ...). This is the same view as `System Settings > Accounts`. I can't find any option to choose which account to assign to Chrome in there.

Android: 9

Google Chrome: 77.0.3865.92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Chrome, tap on menu (top right corner), open settings.
On the first line, you should see your main account or google account 1 according to you..Tap on that.

You should see all the google accounts logged in to your android  device.
Below them, you will find sync option. Tap on that.

It will open a new window with title `Sync`. Find the `syncing to` option, tap on it. Now select which account the data should be synced to.

This will force chrome to use Account2 or whichever chosen account, keeping main account to the OS unchanged

Done!!

Comment: Tapping any account in step 2 doesn't make Chrome use it. Instead it takes me to another list of accounts which includes accounts I created in various apps (Airbnb, Facebook, meetup...)